# How do I delete multiple rows

Tags: python

I have a large file

A sample portion of my file

[image]

The goal is to create a separate file containing only the rows from the original file where type=1 (this is column 1). I have attached the code that I have, It's creating a completly blankfile which is not what I need  need. I feel like I am close but I am missing something.

```
import csv
with open('Test.csv') as f, open('Temp.csv', 'w') as f2:
reader = csv.reader(f)
writer = csv.writer(f2)
for row in reader:
    if row in reader:
        if Typedata not in row:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: You are assigning one to int instead of compare with it. You may have an error when you assign a value to int.

Comment: @hochae thanks, I changed up my code a bit, solved the error but now the file is printing blank as if it's deleting all the rows not just the specific ones. Any suggestions?

Comment: '2' in your date field makes the result.

Comment: you could add example data as DataFrame in code - so we could use it to test solutions

Comment: simply use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Comment: you should get error message because you define `typedata` with lower `t` but later you use `Typedata` with upper `T`.

Comment: I have no idea why you check `if row in reader:` - it makes no sense.

Comment: you show code with wrong indentations inside `with open()`. Put code with original indentations because indentations can change everything and we can't say what can be the real problem.

Comment: How can `delete-row` be a valid tag for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is `if row in reader` which has to get all data from file to check if `row` is in `reader`. And later it has nothing to read, and nothing to write.

You can see it if you put `print(row)` between lines.

I use `in_file = text.splitlines()` only to test it. You should use `open()`.

```
import csv

text = '''FKEY,TYPE,EFF,DATA
34787,2,Y,2022.03.20,1088825
14787,1,Y,2022.03.20,1088825
34787,2,Y,2022.03.20,1088825
14787,1,Y,2022.03.20,1088825
14787,1,Y,2022.03.20,1088825
34787,2,Y,2022.03.20,1088825
14787,1,Y,2022.03.20,1088825
14787,1,Y,2022.03.20,1088825'''

typedata = '2'

#with open('d:/Python/testfile.csv') as in_file, open('d:/Python/Data.csv', 'w') as out_file:
in_file = text.splitlines()
reader = csv.reader(in_file)
#writer = csv.writer(out_file)
for row in reader:
    if typedata not in row:
        print(row)
        #writer.writerow(row)
```

Result:

```
['FKEY', 'TYPE', 'EFF', 'DATA']
['14787', '1', 'Y', '2022.03.20', '1088825']
['14787', '1', 'Y', '2022.03.20', '1088825']
['14787', '1', 'Y', '2022.03.20', '1088825']
['14787', '1', 'Y', '2022.03.20', '1088825']
['14787', '1', 'Y', '2022.03.20', '1088825']
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd like to use just str.split() as I'm not familiar with csv module.
Please check this code.

```
f = open('test.csv')
d = f.read()
f.close()
n = '\n'.join([x for x in d.splitlines() if x.split(',')[1] == '2'])
```

You can save n with a new file opened with 'w' option.